# disable scrolling to cell in focus

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a jtable inside of a scrollpane. how can i stop the scrollpane from scrolling up or down when a cell that is partly out of view gains focus?

the problem is i am setting the cells to editable when the user mouses over them, so when you mouse over a cell that's partly out of view, the view changes suddenly. I don't like this behaviour. any ideas on how to change it?

Comment: scrolling the edited cell into the visible rect is _not_ default behaviour on starting an edit programmatically (via editCellAt, checked jdk 6/7) - could be your code changes the selection along with starting the edit?

Answer (score 2):

You could try calling "setAutoscrolls(false)" on your table.

Although the javadoc talks about handing mouse drag events, it should also disable scrolling on row/cell sections also.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableTest extends JFrame {

    private JTable table;
    /**
     * Create a new TableTest Frame.
     * @param title The title of the frame.
     */
    public TableTest() {

        Object[][] tableData = new Object[][] {
                {1, "One"}, {2, "Two"}, {3, "Three"},
                {4, "Four"}, {5, "Five"}, {6, "Six"}};

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(tableData, new String[] {"A", "B"});
        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setAutoscrolls(false);

        JScrollPane scrolly = new JScrollPane(table);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrolly, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TableTest frame = new TableTest();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: i've tried the suggested method on both the scrollpane and the jtable and neither change the behavior i described.

Comment: Strange.  Unless I've misunderstood what you are trying to do it definately worked for me.  I've posted the example code I used to test this.
You should get different behaviour when the setAutoscrolls(false) call is removed/added.

Comment: related to starting an edit programmatically (f.i. at a cell outside the visible range) the behaviour is uneffected by the autoscrolls property: the editor is _never_ scrolled into the visible rect :-) Looks like @Viktor did something in his custom init code that explicitly changed the selection? Hard to tell after all these years ...

Answer (score 0):

Took me hours of searching but I got it to work for me.

Override this method with your JTable subclass

```
public void scrollRectToVisible(java.awt.Rectangle aRect)
    {
       if(getAutoscrolls())
       super.scrollRectToVisible(aRect);
    }
```

Now `table.setAutoscrolls(false)` should work properly.

Comment: this is violating (at least hard at the borderline of) the contract of scrollRectToVisible: it's _the_ means to scroll an arbitrary part of a component into the visible rect, so must be available unconditionally.